# how to send email verification with firebase hooks in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

there is the code ,what I have to do to send email verification.
I have created a component named register there I want some validation

```
  
  const [
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    emailUser,
    emailloading,
    emailerror,
  ] = useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth);

  const handleRegister = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const name = e.target.name.value
 
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

    e.target.reset();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like you used react hook form.
so use this code it will be sent verification automatically.

```
const [
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    emailUser,
    emailloading,
    emailerror,
  ] = useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, { sendEmailVerification: true });

  const handleRegister = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const email= e.target.email.value //set an email value here
 
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

    e.target.reset();
  }
```